# Trying to save the map in pdf but it's stuck on rendering

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to save a map in pdf but it's stuck on ,,rendering map", and it's not doing something...What can I do in order to solve it? I've downloaded the A3 template map from here https://layout-hub.github.io/ Is it something that I'm doing wrong?
My map:
[image]

The stuck process:
[image]

Layout manager:
[image]

Comment: @BERA yes, I have cubic pyramids, so I think that's the problem...